# Can we use AVAudiorecorder in swift playgrounds?

Tags: ios, swift, avaudiorecorder

I am trying to prototype code in playgrounds before putting it into my app. Can we record Audio using swift playgrounds and how?

Many thanks,

Feras A.

Below is my current attempt, But the audioFile does not have any length, properties or data :-

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

var soundRecorder: AVAudioRecorder!
let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
let OutputFilePath = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("out.wav")

//set the settings for recorder
var recordSettings = [
    AVFormatIDKey: kAudioFormatAppleLossless,
    AVEncoderAudioQualityKey : AVAudioQuality.max.rawValue,
    AVEncoderBitRateKey : 320000,
    AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
    AVSampleRateKey : 44100.0
] as [String : Any]

try soundRecorder = AVAudioRecorder(url: OutputFilePath, settings: recordSettings)
soundRecorder.record(forDuration: 10)
let audioFile = try AVAudioFile(forReading: OutputFilePath)
```

Comment: Have you googled it?

Comment: Or have you tried *anything*?

Comment: Paul - yes, no native swift answer, audioKit does it.

Comment: @PaulKertscher I have edited the post to show my current attempt.

Comment: Alright, that's an improvement. If you described how this is not working I might be tempted to revoke my downvote.

Comment: @PaulKertscher I have edited the post - basically the audioFile does not have any length, properties or data

Comment: In trying your code in a playground I noticed that it is generating an error that is not captured. `Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=1718449215` appears to be `FormatNotSupported`. If I change the file type to `out.caf` then it at least generates a file.

Comment: @FerasAS How you can record audio in playground. Even you can't do it in a simulator. You need real device.

Comment: @dahiya_boy That has changed, the simulator can now record and play audio. See [Apple documentation](https://help.apple.com/simulator/mac/current/#/deve63797392)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible. Since there is no device to record the audio but I think you can connect an external device and use it as your simulator